# Solve for the Number in the number..square..cube relationship

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, no-computers

Each letter stands for a distinct digit...no computer or calculator needed. Just pure logic and some mental multiplication.

CUBE is a concatenated number and it is a cube. X denotes multiplication.

(CUBE) = (N - U + M - B + E + R ) x (( S + Q + U + A - R )x E))

Find all the digits-corresponding to each number without using computer or calculator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We know

> C is not zero (leading zeroes are generally frowned on).
>  E is not zero (we multiply by E on the right side).
>  The cube must be between 11^3 and 21^3 to be a four digit number not ending in 0, and can't be 20^3.  That leaves 10 possibilities.
>  The cube must have all four digits distinct.
>  That rules out 11^3 (which starts and ends with 1), leaving 9 possibilities.
>  Some mental multiplication gives possibilities for those 9:
>  (12) 1728, (13) 2197, <s>(14) 2744, (15) 3375,</s> (16) 4096, (17) 4913, (18) 5832, (19) 6859, (21) 9261.
>  We rule out two of those nine for repetition of digits.
>  That cuts it to 7, giving us 7 choices for CUBE.

Now ...

> We know we multiply by E to get CUBE, so CUBE must have E as one of its factors.
>  That rules out 2197, 4096, 4913, 6859.
>  We're down to just 1728, 5832, and 9261 as choices for CUBE.

So now we look at those.

> 9261 = (N-2+M-6+1+R) x (S+Q+2+A-R) x 1  // left to assign: 0,3,4,5,7,8
>    the max N+M+R can be is 5+7+8=20 so the first term can be at most 13.
>    there's no way the second term can be large enough to make the equation true.  **Eliminated.**
>
>  5832 = (N-8+M-3+2+R) x (S+Q+8+A-R) x 2  // left to assign: 0,1,4,6,7,9
>    the max N+M+R can be is 6+7+9=22 so the first term can be at most 13.
>    there's no way the second term can be large enough to make the equation true.  **Eliminated.**

Which leaves

> 1728 = (N-7+M-2+8+R) x (S+Q+7+A-R) x 8  // left to assign: 0,3,4,5,6,9
>  The x 8 means the other two terms only need to reach a product of 216.
>  N+M+R can be between 0+3+4=7 and 5+6+9=20 so the first term could be between 6 and 19.
>  S+Q+A-R similarly can be between 0+3+4-9=-2 and 5+6+9-0=20 so 2nd term is between 5 and 25.
>  216 has factors of 6,8,9,12,18,24 in those ranges, and 216 = 12 x 18.

From that we can do some directed guessing ...

> 12x18 seems like a good place to look.
>  First term of 18 means N+M+R=19 so 4,6,9 is the only triplet that works.
>  That leaves 12 and S,Q,A of 0,3,5, with S+Q+A-R=5.
>  This would require R=3 which doesn't work.
>
>  Flip it?
>  First term of 12 means N+M+R=13 so 0,4,9 or 3,4,6 are possible triplets.
>  Second term of 18 means S+Q+A-R=11.
>  For N,M,R from 0,4,9 we'd have 3,5,6 for S,Q,A; S+Q+A-R=11 requires R=3, doesn't work.
>  For N,M,R from 3,4,6 we'd have 0,5,9 for S,Q,A; S+Q+A-R=11 requires R=3, so let's go with that.

Now we can fill in what we know.

> C=1, U=7, B=2, E=8, R=3, (S,Q,A) are from (0,5,9), (N,M) are from (4,6).

At this point,

> if there's any way to distinguish between S,Q,A or N,M, I don't see it.
>  So there are 12 valid solutions:
>  C=1, U=7, B=2, E=8, R=3, S=0, Q=5, A=9, N=4, M=6
>  C=1, U=7, B=2, E=8, R=3, S=0, Q=9, A=5, N=4, M=6
>  C=1, U=7, B=2, E=8, R=3, S=5, Q=0, A=9, N=4, M=6
>  C=1, U=7, B=2, E=8, R=3, S=5, Q=9, A=0, N=4, M=6
>  C=1, U=7, B=2, E=8, R=3, S=9, Q=0, A=5, N=4, M=6
>  C=1, U=7, B=2, E=8, R=3, S=9, Q=5, A=0, N=4, M=6
>  C=1, U=7, B=2, E=8, R=3, S=0, Q=5, A=9, N=6, M=4
>  C=1, U=7, B=2, E=8, R=3, S=0, Q=9, A=5, N=6, M=4
>  C=1, U=7, B=2, E=8, R=3, S=5, Q=0, A=9, N=6, M=4
>  C=1, U=7, B=2, E=8, R=3, S=5, Q=9, A=0, N=6, M=4
>  C=1, U=7, B=2, E=8, R=3, S=9, Q=0, A=5, N=6, M=4
>  C=1, U=7, B=2, E=8, R=3, S=9, Q=5, A=0, N=6, M=4
>
>  (CUBE) = (N - U + M - B + E + R ) x (( S + Q + U + A - R )x E))
>  1728 = ((N+M=10)-7-2+8+3) x (S+Q+A=14)+7-3) x 8 = 12 x 18 x 8 ... yup.
>
>  Note, too, that we did this analysis for the factorization of 216=12x18.
>  We didn't look at 216=9x24, which gives still more valid solutions.
>
>  I had really hoped there'd be a unique solution.

Comment: When I eventually used a computer *V qvfpbirerq gurer ner zber fbyhgvbaf ohg V pnaabg fnl jul ng guvf fgntr be hfr vg va zl nafjre orpnhfr vg vf* **inadmissible**.

Answer (score 1):

My thinking so far.

> There are 10 numbers that are a 4-digit CUBE
>  1000
>  1331
>  1728
>  2179
>  2744
>  3375
>  4096
>  4913
>  5832
>  6859
>  8000
>  9261
>
>  I know the digits are all different, so this reduces the list to
>  1728
>  2179
>  4096
>  4913
>  5832
>  6859
>  9261
>
>  Now, the maximum value that N + M + E + R - U - B can be is 29.
>  And, the maximum value that S + Q + U + A - R can be is 30 (even with overlapping values).
>  So their maximum product is 870 and so E cannot be 1. This rules out one more value, leaving
>  1728
>  2179
>  4096
>  4913
>  5832
>  6859
>
>  The CUBE cannot be the cube of any of the three primes 13, 17, 19 because E cannot be those values, or their squares, or 1, ruling our three more. Now there are
>  1728
>  4096
>  5832
>
>  The second of those can be removed because E = 6 and 4096 is indivisible by 6. Now
>  1728
>  5832
>
>  Now exploring 5832, and looking for the largest product of the first two operands. The value R is added to one operand and subtracted from the other, so to maximise their product R = 0.
>  0 R
>  1
>  2 E
>  3 B
>  4
>  5 C
>  6
>  7
>  8 U
>  9
>
>  The first operand is N + M + E + R - U - B = N + M - 9, max is 9 + 7 - 9 = 7.
>  The second operand is S + Q + U + A - R = S + Q + A + 8, max is 6 + 4 + 1 + 8 = 19.
>  The third operand E =  2.
>  But 7 x 19 x 2 = 266 which is not large enough.
>
>  Taking them the other way around:
>  The second operand is S + Q + U + A - R = S + Q + A + 8, max is 9 + 7 + 6 + 8 = 30.
>  The first operand is N + M + E + R - U - B = N + M - 9, max is 4 + 1 - 9 = -4.
>  Their product is giving a negative number.
>
>  So **CUBE = 1728**.
>
>  It needs more number wrangling from here, covered in another answer.

---

Edit:

> There cannot be a unique solution, because N + M in the first operand has two variants for any given solution, and S + Q + A in the second operand and has six variants.

Comment: (You may want to look at my answer before you spend too much time numbers wrangling. You're following pretty closely in my footsteps. Great minds ...)

Comment: @Rubio I avoided looking too closely at your answer, only enough to make sure I wasn't taking quite the same route.

Answer (score 0):

> Sorting from the 4 digit cubes, we find that only possibility is 1728 ( last digit is factor of the number along with other factors being small enough to arrange as the sum of one digit numerals)

Now substitute and solve

> ( judgement + hit and trial),

Hence:

> S=9, Q=5, A=0, N=6, M=4, R=3, C=1, U=7, B=2, E=8
>  There can other soultions, shuffling between (5,9,0) for (S,Q,A) and (4,6) for (M,N).

Comment: Isn't this pretty much exactly what my answer already says?

Comment: Yeah kind of... I didn't know you had answered it earlier and didn't see it. Sorry about that.